# Android Studio Camera App Saving to Internal Storage

Tags: java, android

Currently looking for help on saving images from a camera app to internal storage do to Nexus not having an SD card, our current code saves the photos taken to an SD card folder and the quality is not good.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private ImageView imageHolder;
    private final int requestCode = 20;
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.test1.cam.camapp.MESSAGE";



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imageHolder = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.captured_photo);
        Button capturedImageButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.photo_button);
        capturedImageButton.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent photoCaptureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(photoCaptureIntent, requestCode);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(this.requestCode == requestCode && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");

            String partFilename = currentDateFormat();
           storeCameraPhotoInSDCard(bitmap, partFilename);




            // display the image from SD Card to ImageView Control
            String storeFilename = "photo_" + partFilename + ".jpg";
            Bitmap mBitmap = getImageFileFromSDCard(storeFilename);
            imageHolder.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);
        }
    }

    public void showGreetings(View view)
    {

        String button_text;
        button_text = ((Button) view) .getText().toString();
        if(button_text.equals("Info"))
        {

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else if (button_text.equals("Info"))
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }



    }
    public void saveImage(Context context, Bitmap b,String name,String extension){
        name=name+"."+extension;
        FileOutputStream out;
        try {
            out = context.openFileOutput(name, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
            out.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private String currentDateFormat(){
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HH_mm_ss");
        String  currentTimeStamp = dateFormat.format(new Date());
        return currentTimeStamp;
    }


    private void storeCameraPhotoInSDCard(Bitmap bitmap, String currentDate){
        File outputFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "photo_" + currentDate + ".jpg");
        try {
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fileOutputStream);
            fileOutputStream.flush();
            fileOutputStream.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private Bitmap getImageFileFromSDCard(String filename){
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        File imageFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + filename);
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(imageFile);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bitmap;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To improve the image quality you should change compression to PNG, or change the second parameters to 100 (PNG is lossless and will ignore second params).

```
        b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
```

To change external into internal just change

```
File outputFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "photo_" + currentDate + ".jpg");
```

into

```
File outputFile = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "photo_" + currentDate + ".jpg");
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the response. Attempting to change to getFilesDir() getting an error Saying Cannot Resolve Method? Appreciate any assistance.

Comment: @Gary I'm sorry it should be context, not Environment

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, attempted apply the edit above with using context, now getting this error: Non static method 'getFilesDir()' cannot be refrenced from a static context

Comment: @Gary If you're in activity, don't use context.getFilesDir(). Just use getFilesDir() on your MainActivity.

Comment: It is now not saving to the SD card but I cannot find where it is saving the picture, is there anyway to save the picture to a custom folder with a name of my choice? If this is possible that would be a great help!

Comment: I attempted to changed and getting some errors, 
    private String saveImageToInternalDrive() {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        OutputStream outputStream;

        Context mImageView = null;
        bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) mImageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

        File filePath = getFilesDir();

        File imageDir = new File(filePath.getAbsolutePath() + "YourDirName");
        if(!imageDir.exists()){
            imageDir.mkdir();
        }

Answer (score 0):

The image you are trying to save returns you jest the thumbnail of the actual image that is why you are getting low quality image. You should pass the image name to the intent to save the high quality image when it is captured
Following Helper class that I use for image capture may be of some help to you

```
public class CaptureImageHelper {

    private static final int DEFAULT_WIDTH = 1024;        // min pixels
    private static final int DEFAULT_HEIGHT = 768;        // min pixels
    private static final String TEMP_IMAGE_NAME = "tempImage";


    public static Intent getImageCaptureIntent(Context context, String title) {
        Intent chooserIntent = null;
        List<Intent> intentList = new ArrayList<>();
        Intent takePhotoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        takePhotoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(getTempFile(context)));
        intentList = addIntentsToList(context, intentList, takePhotoIntent);
        if (intentList.size() > 0) {
            chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(intentList.remove(intentList.size() - 1), title);
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentList.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));
        }
        return chooserIntent;

    }

    private static File getTempFile(Context context) {
        //Note you can change the path here according to your need
        File imageFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), TEMP_IMAGE_NAME);
        imageFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        return imageFile;
    }

    private static List<Intent> addIntentsToList(Context context, List<Intent> list, Intent intent) {
        List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
        for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resInfo) {
            String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
            Intent targetedIntent = new Intent(intent);
            targetedIntent.setPackage(packageName);
            list.add(targetedIntent);
        }
        return list;
    }

    public static Bitmap getImageFromResult(Context context, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
        return getImageFromResult(context, DEFAULT_WIDTH, DEFAULT_HEIGHT, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);
    }

    public static Bitmap getImageFromResult(Context context, int width, int height, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
        Bitmap bm = null;
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri selectedImage;
            File imageFile = getTempFile(context);
            selectedImage = Uri.fromFile(imageFile);
            bm = getImageResized(context, selectedImage, width, height);
            int rotation = getRotation(context, selectedImage, true);
            bm = rotate(bm, rotation);
        }
        return bm;
    }

    private static Bitmap getImageResized(Context context, Uri selectedImage, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        System.gc();
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        Bitmap actuallyUsableBitmap = null;
        AssetFileDescriptor fileDescriptor = null;
        try {
            fileDescriptor = context.getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(selectedImage, "r");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        }
        if (null != fileDescriptor) {
            BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor(), null, options);
            // Calculate inSampleSize
            options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);
            // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
            actuallyUsableBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor(), null, options);
        }
        return actuallyUsableBitmap;
    }

    private static Bitmap getImageResized(Context context, Uri selectedImage) {
        return getImageResized(context, selectedImage, DEFAULT_WIDTH, DEFAULT_HEIGHT);
    }

    private static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

            final int halfHeight = height / 2;
            final int halfWidth = width / 2;

            // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
            // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
            while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                    && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
                inSampleSize *= 2;
            }
        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }

    private static int getRotation(Context context, Uri imageUri, boolean isCamera) {
        int rotation;
        if (isCamera) {
            rotation = getRotationFromCamera(context, imageUri);
        } else {
            rotation = getRotationFromGallery(context, imageUri);
        }
        return rotation;
    }

    private static int getRotationFromCamera(Context context, Uri imageFile) {
        int rotate = 0;
        try {
            context.getContentResolver().notifyChange(imageFile, null);
            ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(imageFile.getPath());
            int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                    ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                    ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

            switch (orientation) {
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                    rotate = 270;
                    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                    rotate = 180;
                    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                    rotate = 90;
                    break;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return rotate;
    }

    private static int getRotationFromGallery(Context context, Uri imageUri) {
        int orientation = 0;
        String[] columns = {MediaStore.Images.Media.ORIENTATION};
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(imageUri, columns, null, null, null);
        if (null != cursor && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int orientationColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(columns[0]);
            orientation = cursor.getInt(orientationColumnIndex);
            cursor.close();
        }
        return orientation;
    }

    private static Bitmap rotate(Bitmap bm, int rotation) {
        if (rotation != 0) {
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            matrix.postRotate(rotation);
            return Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight(), matrix, true);
        }
        return bm;
    }
}
```